# How to make synchronous api calls in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I run this code:

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
const get = async () => {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(url);
        let res = await response.json();
        console.log(res);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

(async function () {
    await get();
})();

console.log("I am outside");
```

I get the following output:

`$ node index.js`
`I am outside`
`{ userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false }`

Why I am not getting output in reverse order, even though I have await for async functions?

Comment: because your `console.log` is outside the self executed function, that's why. If you want your console log to be executed after the `get()` you need to add the console log to the line below, not outside the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is awaited:

```
await get()
```

But *this* is not:

```
(async function(){
  await get()
})();
```

If you're using a version of Node which supports top-level `await`, you can await it:

```
await (async function(){
  await get()
})();
```

Or follow up the Promise with a callback:

```
(async function(){
  await get()
})().then(() => {
  console.log('I am outside');
});
```

Alternatively, you can move your logic into the IIFE:

```
(async function(){
  await get();
  console.log('I am outside');
})();
```

Comment: we wont be able to write await keyword outside async function or in main file

Comment: @VenuHegde: Then the other options are to append a `.then()` to the `Promise` or to move the logic into the `async` IIFE.

Comment: @VenuHegde: The three options I could think of are already presented in the answer.  If the first one doesn't work for you, don't just stop reading and give up.  You are encouraged to read the answer in its entirety and try the different options available.  However you structure the logic is really up to you, but the overall pattern is that any operations which rely on the result of an asynchronous operation would need to be invoked in response to that operation, not just placed after it in the code file.

Comment: Thanks @David for you explanations

Answer (score 0):

This part is asynchronous

```
( async function(){
    await get()
})();
```

I can think of two ways to get the text to display first;

1. Move it before the async-function call
2. move it into the function call;

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, as David said, you should put code that you want to run **after** asynchronous code in the defined earlier function's scope. Everything synchronous out of scope will run first

Comment: In the above code it works as you said. but if we have scenario where  output of first api call is needed in second api call?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @VenuHegde: You can redirect an api call to another with body or params you need, don't know if it's ur case or if I understood u right

Answer (score 0):

Because this function

```
( async function(){
    await get()
})();
```

run in asynchronous, so the console.log will print first
If you want run the `get()` first, you should do something like

```
( async function() {
  await get();
  console.log('I am outside')
})
```

or another one

```
( async function() {
  await get();
}).then( () => {
  console.log('I am outside');
})
```